# REST API - create a record in a custom application

Tags: rest-api, custom-object

I am currently testing some Salesforce functionality, we have a suite of forms on our website which when submitted will hopefully create a record in Salesforce.  These records will all be created in custom applications/objects.

I have been able to setup and test the REST API in our form environment, I am currently able to handle create/update/delete of contacts/accounts and leads - to do this part of my code has the url ending:

```
/sobjects/Lead/
```

Does anyone know what to use for custom objects?

Sorry if this is naive I am a beginner with Salesforce.  I have assumed the functionality exists for the REST API however I am prepared to use SOAP if I need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows the same rules as all other uses of custom objects:

```
/sobjects/My_Custom_Object__c/
```

If the object comes from a "managed package", it will also have a "namespace":

```
/sobjects/namespace__My_Custom_Object__c/
```

Comment: I hate it when its so obvious - thanks for clearing it up - having it written so explicitly is such a help sometimes.  Next challenge is to learn and understand the lookup fields and how they work with the api.

Comment: @n34_panda You'll want to look at the examples in the REST API, but basically, they're also straight-forward. If account A has id 001300000000bad, you can associate it to contact C by using `{ "AccountId": "001300000000bad" }`. Give it a try, and I think you'll find it's pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Great thanks - I actually just did, found exactly as you suggest I need to pass the id of the record.  I actually think that is everything I need to migrate my forms from our current app to salesforce...great news.  May even introduce a bit of extra functionality.  I appreciate it